# Grafana graph with prometheus data dynamically starting at zero?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, zero

I have a graph over time (mostly "today so far") and would like to start the graph based on prometheus data at zero. Of course the base value changes everytime the range differs so a static value is useless.

Example:

```
max_over_time(my_metric_counter[${__interval}])
```

This returns a graph starting somewhere (for example 120 in the current time range).
Substracting a static value makes no sense here:

```
max_over_time(my_metric_counter[${__interval}]) - 120
```

I already found out what to do - but it took me quite a while. So I want to share this with you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding a grafana variable as follows:

Name: my_metric_counter_start_value

Type: Query

Hide: Variable

Datasource: MyPrometheusDatasourceName

Refresh: "On time range change"

Query: query_result(min_over_time(my_metric_counter[${__range}]))

Regex: /.*} ([0-9]+) .*/

The I change my graphs query:

```
max_over_time(my_metric_counter[${__interval}]) - $my_metric_counter_start_value
```

And that's it! Hopefully this will help you too ;-)